# Unable to access the data in listview from json in android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Can anyone tell me what this logcat is asking for?

Suggesstions plz.

Thanks for your precious time!..

**StationAdapter**

```
public class StationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stations> {

Context context;
List<Stations> originalList;
List<Stations> temp;
private StationFilter filter;

public StationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Stations> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context ; 

    this.originalList = new ArrayList<Stations>();
    this.originalList.addAll(objects);

    this.temp = new ArrayList<Stations>();
    this.temp.addAll(objects);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null){
        filter  = new StationFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_child, null);




        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_single_item);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Stations stations =originalList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(stations.station_name);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tab_detailsActivity.weatherData=null;
            System.out.println("adap  "+ originalList.get(position).station_name+" "+originalList.get(position).station_code);
            Stations station=originalList.get(position);
            if(station.isCamera){
                Intent intent =new Intent(context,TabhostActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("station_code", station.station_code);
                intent.putExtra("station_name", station.station_name);
                intent.putExtra("isCamera", "YES");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Intent txt_det_intent = new Intent(context, tab_detailsActivity.class);
                txt_det_intent.putExtra("station_code", station.station_code);
                txt_det_intent.putExtra("station_name", station.station_name);
                txt_det_intent.putExtra("isCamera", "NO");
                context.startActivity(txt_det_intent);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class StationFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            ArrayList<Stations> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Stations>();

            for(int i = 0, l = temp.size(); i < l; i++)
            {
                Stations stations= temp.get(i);
                if(stations.station_name.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))
                    filteredItems.add(stations);
            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                result.values = temp;
                result.count = temp.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, 
            FilterResults results) {

        originalList = (ArrayList<Stations>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(originalList.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}}





**Logcat**
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at org.twinkle.weather.StationAdapter.getView(StationAdapter.java:70)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2307)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2004)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1825)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4604)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-07 16:44:46.850: E/AndroidRuntime(21145):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which is your line number 70 in StationAdapter.java. It has assigned "null" value so "Null Pointer Exception" is fired in adapter.

Comment: @ChintanRathod line 70 : holder.name.setText(stations.station_name);

Comment: @ChintanRathod plz visit my question again i have included my adapter for reference

Comment: @ChintanRathod what does mean AbsListview.obtainView(AbsListview.java) ?

Comment: isn't any thing helped from my answer?

Comment: In your Stations Model, try to initialize all the Strings and Objects as default value. If String does not have value to set, it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: @NishantShah: Setting default value could actually solve the problem, but will that be the same case when it comes to business rules. What if the field needs to be empty by default.

Comment: I mean to say, Strings should be initialized to blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have two doubts

1) `stations.station_name` in `holder.name.setText(stations.station_name);` doesn't have any value. Please check whether "station_name" is initialized or not?
2) **holder.name** may be null. Check when you assign `convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_single_item);`, `textview_single_item` is there in your layout.

Comment: If i run my app on 2.2 versioned mobile with the above code, its working fine, but its not working on honeycomb and + versions,my app got crash and shown some errors on logcat what i've given u on my question

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Change this line

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_child, null);
```

**To this**

```
convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_child, parent, false);
```

Comment: I am getting error on this line 67  holder.name.setText(stations.station_name); if i follow your suggestion

Comment: change this line to below and see if u r getting the same error holder.name.setText("No Error Now"); If this works, then its clear that the stations.station_name does not have any value.

Comment: see if i run my app on 2.2 versioned mobile with the above code, its working fine, but its  not working on honeycomb and + versions

Comment: Did you try out the change and run the code on 2.2 and HoneyComb... i mean this line holder.name.setText("No Error Now");

Comment: i got error on this line holder.name.setText("No Error Now"); if i follow your suggestion

Comment: so your holder.name is null... holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_single_item);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31398/discussion-between-nakshatran-and-vinothbabu)